# Usage of though

Tags: word-usage

"You asked us to, and loath though we were to invade a lady's privacy, we did so."

Can anybody tell me what though means here and can I write the sentence in another order like that for instance
You asked us to, and though we were loath to invade a lady's privacy, we did so.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! What research have you done to find the meaning of _though_? Which dictionaries have you referenced? Could you explain why their definitions confuse you?

Comment: There should be a comma after *and*. That aside, I'm not sure what the confusion is.

Comment: @KannE The sentence makes sense as providing nonrestrictive information with the additional comma. Without it, I'd say the first comma is a comma splice. (Try replacing the first comma with a period, making it two sentences.) An alternative is to replace the first comma with a semicolon or a dash.

Comment: I used Cambridge dictionary and learned that it means despite of sth but i also learned from an english dicussion forum that changing the placement of though may have a slight affect on meaning anyway the problem comes when i try to translate it in my head( and unwillingly despite of this to invade a lady's privacy, we did so) it makes no sense to me so i thought maybe it has a different meaning here and that is why i also wanted to change the order to (and despite being unwillingly to invade a lady's privacy we did so)

Comment: I used unwillingly to do sth instead of loath bec loath is kinda new to me and its abit hard to handle using it yet. And here is the link to the forum i talked about above                                             (  https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-position-of-though-in-sentence.1008671/

Comment: Oh i feel so stupid to ask such a question after knowing that it still means despite to sth and really thanks for answering me but just one last question can i say (and though loath we were to invade a lady's privacy,we did so) it just sounds so wrong, to me, to say (and loath though we were to invade...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - *You asked us to, and **loath though we were** to invade a lady's privacy, we did so.*

This is an archaic construction, using a rare word (*loath* 'reluctant; unwilling'),
and putting it up front before the conjunction *though*. 
It's a transform of

- *You asked us to, and **though we were loath** to invade a lady's privacy, we did so.*

So you would do well to write it that way, as you suggest.